# can't rosmake package "3d_navigation"

Tags: 3d-navigation, rosmake, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was told electric doesn't fully support 3d_navigation yet, so I installed ros-diamondback-desktop-full on my Ubuntu 10.04.
However, when I tried to rosmake 3d_navigation, error occurred.

```
  bcddivad@bcddivad-laptop:~$ roscd 3d_navigation/
  bcddivad@bcddivad-laptop:~/code/ros/bcddivad_3d_navigation/3d_navigation$ pwd 
  /home/bcddivad/code/ros/bcddivad_3d_navigation/3d_navigation
  bcddivad@bcddivad-laptop:~/code/ros/bcddivad_3d_navigation/3d_navigation$ ls
  3d_nav_executive  3d_nav_gazebo  octomap_collision_check  pose_follower_3d  sbpl_lattice_planner_3d  stack.xml
  bcddivad@bcddivad-laptop:~/code/ros/bcddivad_3d_navigation/3d_navigation$ rosmake
  [ rosmake ] No package or stack arguments and the current directory is not the correct path for stack '3d_navigation'. Stack directory is: /home/bcddivad/code/ros/openr
  [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: []                                                                                                                                  
  [ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/bcddivad/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120428-185554                                                                              
  [ rosmake ] Expanded args [] to: 
  []                                                                                                                                         
  [ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.                                                                                      
  bcddivad@bcddivad-laptop:~/code/ros/bcddivad_3d_navigation/3d_navigation$ cat /home/bcddivad/.bashrc | tail -n 3
  
  source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash
  export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/bcddivad/code/ros:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks;
```

How can I solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33408/can%27t-rosmake-package-%223d_navigation%22/) by [bcddivad](https://answers.ros.org/users/2223/bcddivad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2012-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look at this error message ( which I assume is truncated):
**No package or stack arguments and the current directory is not the correct path for stack '3d_navigation'. Stack directory is: /home/bcddivad/code/ros/openr**[...]

What is the content of /home/bcddivad/code/ros/... ? Are there more ROS packages there which are named 3d_navigation? There seems to be something wrong with your path setup. I suggest following the instructions on the 3d_navigation wiki page: create a rosinstall file, install that on top of diamondback, and source the setup.bash in that directory. This will ensure that the right packages (only) will be in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2